# React renders with old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am updating my app state in React and I see that the Render method is processed with the old state. What needs to be done that React would render the new state?

Basically I have and Ajax call which either get's called if there was an update or get's skipped. If the Ajax call is skipped and already existing data is used, React does not update the state.

```
 this.setState({
   errorStr: null,
   isSubmitting: false,
   isLoading: false
 });
```

In the `console.log` output which is in `Render` method, I see that `isSubmitting` is still `true`. And thus the updates are never rendered in.

Thanks

Comment: What's your code to detect whether `isSubmitting` is true or false?

Comment: In the Render method I have an if statement.

Comment: did you try with this.setState({
        errorStr: null,
        isSubmitting: false,
        isLoading: false
    }); ? setState is a function and it takes an object in the argument

Comment: Did you copy the code wrong ? It is as @oliv37 says, you are assigning `this.setState` with an object (see your `=` sign), while you really want to call the setState function with your new state object

Comment: Can you share more code? Like whether this.setState is placed inside the ajax call or not.

Answer (score -1):

study this link componentWillMount() and componentDidMount() . use one of this method then your problem will be solved

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: actually, his code is a syntax/assignment issue, he is assigning setState with an object